# Is there a way for a service worker to know the url of the requesting page?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm converting my large legacy application to a PWA and finding that many things don't work, because they were designed with very different assumptions about caching, state, etc. I want to convert the whole site eventually, but I'd like to restrict the scope of the service worker to specific pages, so that I can convert them one by one.

I know that you can limit service worker scope to a sub-directory by placing the service worker in that sub-directory, but that doesn't map well to the order in which I need to do the conversion. I would prefer to have the service worker in the root directory, but implement a whitelist of pages that I want it to handle, until such time as all pages are converted and I can remove the restriction.

Within a service worker, is there a way to access the url of the **referring/current** page, so that I could check to see if it's on the whitelist and allow the fetch, and if not just return?

Or is there a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `FetchEvent.request` has a `referrer` property, which is exactly what I needed. Not sure how I missed this.